# Other apps to manage permissions?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, permissions

I used to use -  and loved - [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite) which allowed you to revoke specific permissions from specific apps.

Ever since AT&T *finally* pushed out Jelly Bean for the S3 though, it no longer works, and puts my phone into a endless reboot loop.

Searching in the market, I couldn't find any other app that does this (though the are plenty that just let you *SEE* the permissions of all your apps).

Anyone know of another app that does the same thing as LBE?

Comment: Do you still have root? I would imagine that if your phone accepted an OTA update from AT&T, you no longer have root. In which case, you'll need to re-root your phone.

Comment: Yes.  You're correct, I did wind up losing root, but I have rerooted. Superuser, ROM Manager, ROM Toolbox,  SQLLite Editor all work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*LBE* works on JellyBean -- just not the version you install from the Playstore. The boot-loop problem is a known issue (so nobody can understand why the developer did not even place a note on the app's playstore page).

On XDA you can find multiple threads discussing this issue, and at least one of them also holds modified versions of *LBE* to download. Take e.g. a look at:

- [[APP] LBE Security Manager v4.3.2738](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1422479) (this is a new version only released in Chinese -- but some XDA members provide a translated version here)
- [[APP][ROOT] LBE Privacy Guard - Most Powerful privacy protection app for Android](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1091065)
- [[APP] LBE Privacy Guard v2 is now available](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1328000)

Alternatives to *LBE* would include:

- [PDroid Privacy Protection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacy.pdroid)
- [PDroid Manager](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/pdroid-manager-the-pdroid-app-alternative/) (Open-Source alternative to it)

Answer (score 0):

A few apps for you to try out:-

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stericson.permissions.donate