# Modern apps to manage app permissions

Tags: applications, permissions

In doing research on app permissions and cool "l33t hax0r" apps to put on a rooted phone, I stumbled across a category of app permission managers.  They seem to be relevant to Android 1.x and 2.x, circa 2010.

The advent of Jelly Bean (Android 4.3) gave us a rudimentary app permission manager within Android, but not everyone got it, Google didn't mean to release it, and it was quickly removed from Android.

Is this category of apps no longer valid?  Or are there just a new bunch of apps and I'm finding stale posts, articles, and information?

I found this article here on [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35473/other-apps-to-manage-permissions), and the answers link to most of the apps that I have come across (modified Google Permission Managers notwithstanding).

The only modern/supported app of similar design is a module for XPosed called  [Xprivacy.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacy-ultimate-android-privacy-app-t2320783)  However, XPosed is only for Samsung ROMs/devices.  Is there something more generic?

I currently have some Samsung phones, and some of them are rooted, but not all the devices I am tinkering with are Samsung or rooted.

Comment: XPosed is not only for Samsung devices. Certain modules may be, but the framework is most certainly not.

Comment: Apart from that, there are much more [permission managers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions) available for Android. I've used LBE for a long time, XPrivacy certainly works on many more devices (I've used it on some), as does DonkeyGuard.

Comment: Donkey Guard works fine for me...It can manage Location,Identity,Media etc permissions as well as can use fake information for particular app (For e.g if for a particular app you dont want to share your no. than you can set some random no. via DonkeyGuard so when that app will try to access your no. it will get that fake no. not the orignal)

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities:

1. Try Advanced Permissions Manager found in the Play Store. But mind you, permissions are not granular. Example, if you deny Location right on an app and it needs *some* aspect of that right, then the app will not run.
2. Xposed's Xprivacy is *very* granular; I can disallow certain aspects of that same app's Location rights, for example. and the app will continue to work.
3. Xposed is not specific to Samsung; it's running on my rooted LG G3.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the [X-Plore file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=fr). It is a very handy tool once you get the hang of it. It has made all the file operations very easier. It uses a two pane user interface which makes working on it easier! You can find a full review of the app [here](http://reviewlagoon.com/x-plore-file-manager-android/).

You can also try the [Advanced permission manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.pmaster&hl=en) which relatively handles permissions better and does not require root.